# Как вывести переменную из if else (незнаю как объяснить правильно)

Tags: php

Ночь в хату! Есть вот такая ерунда с ценой:

```
<? if($row['fp'] == '0.00'){ ?><? echo $row['price'] + $row['np']; ?><? } else echo $row['fp']; ?>
```

FP = фиксированая цена
Price + Np = это цена с надбавкой (свои приколы)

Как видите оно показывает либо одно либо другое в зависимости от заполненого поля. И вот так как я ограничен в познаниях мне нужно это всё дело вывести в перемнную одну что бы внедрить в `'.$peremennaya.'` и она показывала либо фиксированную цену илибо с надбавкой. Всё это ПХП

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял что вообще требуется...

```
if ($row['fp'] == '0.00') {
    $peremennaya = $row['price'] + $row['np'];
} else {
    $peremennaya = $row['fp'];
}
```

или вариант покороче:

```
$peremennaya = $row['fp'] == '0.00' ? $row['price'] + $row['np'] : $row['fp'];
```

использовать так:

```
echo 'Цена: ' . $peremennaya . ' денег'; //Цена: [количество] денег
```

Answer (score 1):

Несложно ведь вроде.

```
if($row['fp'] == '0.00') {
  $price = $row['price'] + $row['np'];
}
else
  $price = $row['fp'];
echo $price;
```